# modify spring bean programatically in runtime using ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I need to modify some spring bean in runtime by webservice. Im using ApplicationContext .

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext configContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext;

ConfigurableListableBeanFactory registery = configContext.getBeanFactory();

registery.registerSingleton("XXX", new MyNewBeanDefintion());
```

in my @Configuration class there is

```
@Bean
public ParentClass campaignSelection(){
if(type.equals("X")) {

return new X();

}
else if(type.equals("Y")){

return new Y();
}

    return null;

}
```

with simply

```
public interface ParentClass {

public Item selectOneItem();

}

public class X implements ParentClass {

@Override
public Item selectOneItem() {
// return item
}
```

}

```
public class Y implements ParentClass {
@Override
public Item selectOneItem() {
 // return item
}
}
```

and i need i need the bean to switch between X , Y in runtime

Comment: What do you mean by modify, update property values or something else? What is the scope of target beans?

Comment: @Evgeny update the bean's injected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace injected instance of `campaignSelection` bean you can use marker interface, e.g.

```
public interface CampaignChangeAware {    
    void onCampaignChange(ParentClass newCampaign);
}
```

Make other classes that have to be updated implement this interface. Then you will be able to update beans using code

```
Map<String, CampaignChangeAware> beansToUpdate = context.getBeansOfType(CampaignChangeAware.class);
for (CampaignChangeAware bean : beansToUpdate.values()) {
    bean.onCampaignChange(newCampaign);
}
```

But it doesn't affect already instantiated beans with scope other that `singleton` as spring doesn't manage such beans.

Comment: but how should i use 

    @Autowired
    private ParentClass parentClass;

Comment: @Hoda Use it as usual. Spring injects necessary instance when bean is created. When you need to update beans just replace injected instance in `onCampaignChange` method, i.e. `parentClass = newCampaign`. For new beans (with prototype scope) your code `@Bean
public ParentClass campaignSelection()` will work perfectely, just replace desired type. For example you can use some static class to hold current type